# How to get the complete URL address most efficiently?

Tags: java, url, url-shortener, bit.ly, tinyurl

I'm using a Java program to get expanded URLs from short URLs. Given a Java `URLConnection`, among the two approaches, which one is better to get the desired result?

```
Connection.getHeaderField("Location");
```

vs

```
Connection.getURL();
```

I guess both of them give the same output. The first approach did not give me the best results, only 1 out of 7 were resolved. Can the efficiency be increased by the second approach?

Can we use any other better approach?

Comment: When you say "short url", do you mean you have something generated from a service like tinyurl or bit.ly?

Comment: yes, precisely but not limited to these two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use the following:

```
@Test
public void testLocation() throws Exception {
    final String link = "http://bit.ly/4Agih5";

    final URL url = new URL(link);
    final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

    final String location = urlConnection.getHeaderField("location");
    assertEquals("http://stackoverflow.com/", location);
    assertEquals(link, urlConnection.getURL().toString());
}
```

With `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` the `HttpURLConnection` does not follow redirects and the destination page (`stackoverflow.com` in the above example) will not be downloaded just the redirect page from `bit.ly`.

One drawback is that when a resolved `bit.ly` URL points to another short URL for example on `tinyurl.com` you will get a `tinyurl.com` link, not what the `tinyurl.com` redirects to.

**Edit**:

To see the reponse of `bit.ly` use `curl`:

```
$ curl --dump-header /tmp/headers http://bit.ly/4Agih5
<html>
<head>
<title>bit.ly</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">moved here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see `bit.ly` sends only a short redirect page. Then check the HTTP headers:

```
$ cat /tmp/headers
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2013 08:48:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private; max-age=90
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 117
X-Cache: MISS from cam
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from cam:3128
Via: 1.1 cam:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE7)
Connection: close
```

It sends a `301 Moved Permanently` response with a `Location` header (which points to `http://stackoverflow.com/`). Modern browsers don't show you the HTML page above. Instead they automatically redirect you to the URL in the `Location` header.

Comment: Can you explain me what are the last two lines doing? The rest of my code is exactly the same.

Comment: And Also if I set FollowRidirects to true, does it affect performance significantly?

Comment: They are [jUnit assertion methods](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), they check whether the first and second parameters are equal or not. In the example they're equal.

Performance: if `instanceFollowRedirects` is `true` you download a page from `bit.ly` and second one where the `bit.ly` redirects to (in the example it's the `stackoverflow.com`). With `false` you download only one page, so you use less bandwidth.

Comment: @palacsint, if i remove the line of "urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);", there will be failure. What's the reason in it?

Comment: @Jacky: I've started to edit the page but I realized that "there will be a faliure" is a little bit ambiguous. What do you mean a "failure"?

Comment: @palacsint, "urlConnection.getHeaderField("location");" will return null if i do that

Comment: @Jacky: I think this case `getHeaderField()` parses headers of the last HTTP requests which is `stackoverflow.com` and it does not return any `Location` header.

Comment: @palacsint bit.ly/9mglq8 doesn't have any Location field in the header. How do I get the expanded url. And one more thing how can one handle the case where there are 2 or 3 redirection?

Comment: @MONUKUMAR: `wget -S bit.ly/9mglq8` shows a `Location` header for me. It must be there unless redirection will not work in browsers. For multiple redirections use a loop with http result code check.

Answer (score 2):

The above link contains a more complete method along the same line as the previous post 
https://github.com/cpdomina/WebUtils/blob/master/src/net/cpdomina/webutils/URLUnshortener.java